# How can i insert different size image in the center of the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i insert different size image in box centered?
Image has a different size .
portrait (height is bigger than width),
landscape (width is bigger than height),
square (width is same as a height)
and The red box has a convertible size.(not only square)

[image: The red box is a visible section. Image has a different size like portrait, landscape, square]

I use a code like this

HTML

```
<div class="image">
  <img class="image_insert" src="..">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image_insert{
    max-width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
function imageControl(){
 var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image_insert');
 var array = new Array();

 for(var i=0; i<image.length; i++){
  if(image[i].width>image[i].height){
    $(image[i]).css("max-width","none");
    $(image[i]).css("height","100%");
    }
  }
}
```

It worked. But this way depends on document(image,javascript) loading time, so there are any best way to insert different size image in the center of the box?
***There are no empty space exists inner Red box!**

Comment: see this it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/marvo/3k3CC/2/

Comment: So what you want the outer image of the border should be hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #BC2424;;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400/" /><div class="img-rectangle"></div></div>
<div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" /><div class="img-rectangle"></div></div>
<div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /><div class="img-rectangle"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use the `<picture>` [HTML element tag](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element), with sources appropriate to the media queries for the various situations (eg landscape vs portait, screen resolution/DPIs, etc). The browser will then load the appropriate image automatically.

[This blog post](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice) should give some additional context on how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

use inline-flex box to align the images, I have created this fiddle to show the usage https://jsfiddle.net/swvdfzax/

the CSS will be

```
div.image{
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border:2px solid red;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  vertical-align:top
}
div.image img{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

and the HTML will be

```
<div class="image"><img src="...path/to/image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$(function(){
 $(".image_insert").each(function(){
   var container = $(this).parent();
    var img = $(this);
   img.css({
     left: -1 * (img.width()/2 - container.width()/2),
      top: -1 * (img.height()/2 - container.height()/2)      
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.image{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.image_insert{   
    position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <img class="image_insert" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400/">
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img class="image_insert" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img class="image_insert" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/">
</div>
```

JSFiddel demo here https://jsfiddle.net/g868ae1h/1